# Adding a new column to a dataframe that contains a hash of a select few columns combined

Tags: python, dataframe

I am struggling with figuring out the best way to do this we want to create a hash of the columns per a row and add that hash as a new column. So each row will have its own hash. I was thinking of using dataframe.apply, but am not sure on how to format the call properly and am not seeing a good example for what I am describing in docs.

Original data frame:

```
user_id     user_jumps  d_steps
   1015       48          0
   1015       23        -25
   1015       79         56
   2023       10          0
   2023       20         10
```

Output Data Frame:

```
user_id     steps    d_steps   hash
   1015       48          0    hash(user_id+Steps+d_steps)
   1015       23        -25    hash(user_id+Steps+d_steps)
   1015       79         56    hash(user_id+Steps+d_steps)
   2023       10          0    hash(user_id+Steps+d_steps)
   2023       20         10    hash(user_id+Steps+d_steps)
```

Comment: would df['hash'] = hash((df['user_id'],df['steps'],df['d_steps'])) solve it?(your second dataframe is different columns but same data, just rename if need?)

Comment: I would be taking the output of the hash and inputting it into a new column. So the 4th column would be added onto the data frame, then the apply function used to fill out the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an apply function on each row:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']], columns=['user_id', 'steps', 'd_steps'])

print(
df.apply(lambda x: hash(x['user_id'] + x['steps'] + x['d_steps']), axis=1)
)
```

This means:
For each row of the df, take the concatenation of user_id, steps and d_steps and apply the hash.

Comment: Savior thank you. Just picked python up for work, do still learning.

Comment: No problem. Look for some examples of Pandas apply, sometimes it's a bit unintuitive but it's very useful

Answer (score 0):

Depends what kind of hash you want, but I would just iterate through the column and calculate the hash of the sum (as an encoded string) as such:

`

```
# import your stuff
import pandas as pd
import haslib
# create a sample dataframe
d = {'user_id': [1, 2], 'user_jumps': [3, 4], 'd_steps':[5,6]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
# create a column of the sum of the first two columns
df['hash']=df['user_id']+df['user_jumps']+df['d_steps']
temp_list=[]
# iterate through the new column you created,
# and append its hash to a temp list for now
for val in df['hash'].values.tolist():
    m = hashlib.sha256()
    print(val)
    # encode first
    m.update(str(val).encode("UTF-8"))
    # then append the result to the list
    temp_list.append(m.digest())
# append the list you created back to that column
df['hash']=temp_list
```

`

Comment: Wouldn't this be an antipattern for dataframes?